# Repeating blocks of code used throughout multiple functions in class - how to apply DRY

Tags: php, oop, dry

I am using **php**, I have a class with 10 functions which share some repeating code like in the following

```
class A
{

    function car()
    {
        $t = [];
        ...

        ...
        $t .= 'CAR ' . implode(', ', $t);
        $this->someFunc($t);

        return $this;
     }


     function bike()
     {
        $t = [];
        ...

        ...
        $t .= 'BIKE ' . implode(', ', $t);
        $this->someFunc($t);

        return $this;
     }

     ...

}
```

Within the functions I placed "**...**" which represents code that differs in each function, however all 10 functions start with a empty local **$t** array, and end with **$t** being flattened and passed to another function, finally **$this** being returned.

How can we apply **DRY** to this, isit even possible? - I am thinking there maybe some way to write this once.

Regards

Comment: A more real-world example might make this more answerable.

Comment: @ceejayoz This is pretty much as it is in my real-world code, just with the middle parts removed for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, to apply the DRY, you have to answer this question: **What differs all the time and what remains the  same?** Seeing at your code, it looks obvious that only `CAR | BIKE` do differ. So according to this, you can *abstract* your calls, like this:

```
class A
{
     protected function prepare($t, $type)
     {
        $t .= $type . implode(', ', $t);
        $this->addToString($t);

        return $this;
     }


     public function car()
     {
         $t = [];
         ....

         return $this->prepare($t, 'CAR');
     }

     public function bike()
     {
        $t = [];
        ...

        return $this->prepare($t, 'BIKE');
     }
}
```

Comment: Where do I stick my middle differing part of code(represented by "**...**")

Comment: You didn't post it, so by default I assumed it was the same. Maybe you could post your middle part?

Comment: The point of DRY: *Take parts of your code that differ, and make them function parameters, and leave the rest into another function*

Comment: you haven't read my question properly, I said "..." is represented by different code in each of the 10 functions the opening post, posting it would be pointless.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was in hurry. Since `$t` looks as a result of particular call, then it would not make sense to abstract it as well. See my edit if it helps

Comment: the edit seems better and I may end up implementing it, however I am still curious if its possible to do with the **$t** too. In my example its not too important, but for the purpose of the question I would still like to know, perhaps in the future **$t** may consist of much more repeating code. Also regarding your edit, it maybe possible to remove the 'CAR | BIKE' parameter from your function? perhaps there is a way to check which function called that function? as CAR | BIKE is the actual name of the function.

Comment: As for simplifying function 2-nd method's argument, you can surely add this `$type = strtoupper($type);` into `prepare()`'s method and the call it like `return $this->prepare($t, __FUNCTION__);`, but that's all about improvements, I just tried to give you a point

Comment: If `$t` was the last thing after `...`, then yeah, it will be much easier not to initialize it all the time, and put all that *preparation* logic into `prepare()` method. But since `$t` comes first, I don't see any easiest way of how to get rid of it. References come to mind, but they aren't good practice to follow